# kOps 1.19 reports error "Unauthorized" when interfacing with AWS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, kops, nlb

I'm following the kOps tutorial to set up a cluster on AWS. I am able to create a cluster with

```
kops create cluster
kops update cluster --yes
```

However, when validating whether my cluster is set up correctly with

```
kops validate cluster
```

I get stuck with error:

```
unexpected error during validation: error listing nodes: Unauthorized
```

The same error happens in many other kOps operations.

I checked my kOps/K8s version and it is 1.19:

```
> kops version
Version 1.19.1 (git-8589b4d157a9cb05c54e320c77b0724c4dd094b2)

> kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20" ...
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19" ...
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As of kOps 1.19 there are two reasons you will suddenly get this error:

1. If you delete a cluster and reprovision it, your old admin is not removed from the kubeconfig and kOps/kubectl tries to reuse it.
2. New certificates have a TTL of 18h by default, so you need to reprovision them about once a day.

Both issues above are fixed by running `kops export kubecfg --admin`.

Note that using the default TLS credentials is discouraged. Consider things like using an OIDC provider instead.

Comment: Oh interesting, I might have been hit by (1), and the fix I mentioned in another answer also required me to export kubecfg again, so that might have incidentally fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Even if I use kops export kubecfg --admin, the Kubeconfig file that I get still has a TTL of 18 hours (although the cluster validation runs fine)
@Ole is that what you observed too?

Comment: Yes. For security reasons, that is the intended behaviour.

Comment: For a solution to get back the old behavior, taken from: https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/releases/1.19-NOTES.md, you need to provide the ttl when exporting the credentials, ex: `kops export kubecfg --admin=87600h`

Comment: Strongly discourage creating unrevocable long-lived certificates like that. At the moment, rolling cluster CA involves extended API outage.

Answer (score 3):

Kubernetes v1.19 removed basic auth support, incidentally making the default kOps credentials unable to authorize. To work around this, we will update our cluster to use a Network Load Balancer (NLB) instead of the default Classic Load Balancer (CLB). The NLB can be accessed with non-deprecated AuthZ mechanisms.

After creating your cluster, but before updating cloud resources (before running with `--yes`), edit its configuration to use a NLB:

```
kops edit cluster
```

Then update your load balancer class to `Network`:

```
spec:
  api:
    loadBalancer:
      class: Network
```

Now update cloud resources with

```
kops update cluster --yes
```

And you'll be able to pass AuthZ with kOps on your cluster.

Note that there are several other advantages to using an NLB as well, [check the AWS docs for a comparison](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/features/).

If you have a pre-existing cluster you want to update to a NLB, there are more steps to follow to ensure clients don't start failing AuthZ, to delete old resources, etc. You'll find a better guide for that in the [kOps v1.19 release notes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/permalinks/acm_nlb.md).

Comment: kOps does not use basic auth by default though. This is typically used if you use ACM certs on the API ELB.