# kops export kubeconfig with no diminishing TTL

Tags: kubernetes, kops

We create the cluster using the following command

```sh
kops create cluster --node-count=3 --node-size=c5.2xlarge --master-count=3 --master-size=c5.xlarge --zones=eu-west-1a --name=${KOPS_CLUSTER_NAME} --yes
```

We are using kops cluster. We export the kubeconfig using this command

```sh
$ kops export kubecfg --admin --kubeconfig ~/workspace/kubeconfig --state=s3://YOUR-S3-BUCKET-NAME"
```

It works fine for sometime. But after sometime we again start getting the same error as TTL expires for kubeconfig

```sh
error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized) kops
```

Is there any way we can get rid of this annoying TTL?

Comment: Dupilicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66341494/kops-1-19-reports-error-unauthorized-when-interfacing-with-aws-cluster?

Comment: Thanks a lot @OleMarkusWith but i am already exporting the kubeconfig as `--admin`. It only solves the issue for sometime but i get the same error again.

Comment: As mentioned there, the cert you export expires after 18h

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks a lot. But we have daily deployments running using the exported kubeconfig, is there a way for longer validity ? I mean we can't generate a `kubeconfig` daily for sure.  @OleMarkusWith

Comment: The admin cert is very privileged. Your deployment systems should not use that. Consider dedicated credentials per pipeline instead.

Comment: @codeaprendiz Does Ole Markus With's comment answer all your questions ?

Comment: @matt_j, the problem still remains, I want to be able to generate `kubeconfig` which does not have a diminishing TTL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After going through the [docs](https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/cli/kops_export_kubecfg/), found that we can actually give the validity of the `kubeconfig` as an argument

```sh
$ kops export kubecfg --admin=87600h0m0s --kubeconfig ~/workspace/kubeconfig --state=s3://<bucket-name> --name=<cluster-name>
```

Comment: Awesome that you did all the leg work and posted back.

Comment: Seriously — thanks a ton for coming back to this and sharing your hard-won knowledge!

Comment: Great work for sharing the answer, however, the link you provided is returning 404, https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/cli/kops_export_kubeconfig/#examples this is a usage sample to follow

Comment: Yeah looks like they updated the docs link. Thank you.